# Copy all formatting from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to copy value from one sheet to another

```
Lastrow = WAEnv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Xrow = 1

lcol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lcol).Address(True, False), "$")

Debug.Print Xrow
For Rw = 3 To Lastrow
    Set Rng = WAEnv.Range("A" & Rw & ":" & vArr(0) & Rw)

    If Rng(1, 1).Value > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve DstArr(1 To lcol, 1 To Xrow)
        Xcol = 1

        For Each cl In Rng.Columns.Cells
            DstArr(Xcol, Xrow) = cl.Value
            Xcol = Xcol + 1
        Next cl

        WAPatch.Cells(Xrow, 1).RowHeight = Rng(1, 1).RowHeight
        Xrow = Xrow + 1
    End If
Next Rw

WAPatch.Range("A3").Resize(UBound(DstArr, 2), UBound(DstArr, 1)).Formula = Application.Transpose(DstArr)
```

I already know that I can use to cpy all formatting but the below code is very slow so I am using the above mentioned array method.

```
WAEnv.Cells(i, j).Copy
WAPatch.Cells(ro, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

What I am looking for if there is a way to copy paste all formatting from one sheet to another using the array method I have been using?

Comment: Use `xlPasteFormats` to paste just the formatting.  The fastest way to do this is to apply it to all the cells you will be applying this to in a single pass, ie copy it from one row in your source then paste it to all the roles at once.